# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, ubuntu

I just manually installed a new plugin on my WordPress site, created a table in MySQL for the plugin's entries, and when I try to open the page that uses the plugin, I receive this error:

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'to-do_list'): An error occurred while 
connecting to the database 'wordpress_clouse'. The error reported by the 
server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server 
through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

This is the MySQL info listed in my config file (which I believe is correct):

```
"type" => "Mysql",
"user" => "root",
"pass" => "******",
"host" => "localhost",
"port" => "",
"db"   => "******"
```

This is the main contents of the /etc/my.cnf file:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#port       = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
#port       = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
log_error   = mysqld.err

skip-networking
```

I've looked at answers to similar errors but none of the solutions worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL can listen on either `TCP socket` or `unix domain socket` or both. Your server config is set to listen on unix domain socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` but your client is connecting to unix domain socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

Comment: @alvits: Would the solution be to point the client to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution.

Comment: I assume that would be written somewhere in the plugin? I did a quick search of the plugin and there was no mention of "mysql.sock"

Comment: If it is hard to reconfig wordperss, I'd suggest reconfiguring MySQL. `Stop MySQL`, modify `/etc/my.cnf` to use the socket that worpress expects . Finally `start MySQL`. Only do this if wordpress is the only client of this MySQL, otherwise it will be hard to reconfigure all clients.

Comment: If everything else fail, use TCP socket.

Comment: Just an FYI, when I changed host to `127.0.0.1` and port `3306`, I received this message: `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`. Don't know if this adds any new info. Also, if I modify my.cnf to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`, wouldn't the .sock file need to be there?

Comment: You don't need to move the socket file. MySQL creates the socket on startup in the location pointed by `/etc/my.cnf`. If you prefer to use TCP socket, then you will need to enable port in /etc/my.cnf and configure wordpress to connect to localhost on port 3306 (or whatever port /etc/my.cnf specifies). Always shutdown MySQL before editing /etc/my.cnf.

Comment: Just tried your advice, when I restarted WordPress, it said "Error establishing database connection." I'll give TCP socket a try and report back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45154/discussion-between-eric-matthew-turano-and-alvits)

Comment: What were the other solutions that you tried but didn't work?

Comment: @AndyLester See my answer below for what worked for me. Connecting via TCP didn't work for me, and then I tried the below solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what helped me solve this problem, which was that the actual file directory on my server was */var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock*, not /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock:

1. Open your **my.cnf** file
2. Add the following to your `[client]` section (if you don't have a `[client]` section, then add it). It should look like this:

> [client]
>
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

The error should be gone. Many thanks to @alvits for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Useful answer, though you don't need to restart the mysql server as it's a client, not a server, setting that you're changing.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same error and found it was because I haven't started the service yet.

Executed the command `systemctl start mariadb` and then connected to the MariaDB server using the command `mysql` and it worked.

Hope it helps

Comment: My site abnormally goes down, today and your answer saved me. but can you please tell me what could cause this. my site is on WordPress i am using amazon instance m4.xlarge. my site starts showing error "Error establishing a database connection". where should I look? thanks anyways. great help.

Comment: If the DB is getting disconnected, I'm assuming the reason is that mariadb not starting on boot, try doing this "systemctl enable mariadb". hope that helps.